# How do you compare the ASCII value of a cell in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to loop through a sheet and highlight 'blank' cells. Some of these blank cells have spaces, newlines, etc. and aren't playing nice. Here's my code:

```
Dim Kibble as String


For i = 1 To coor(1)
Columns(i).Select
    For k = 1 To coor(2)
        Kibble = Cells(k, i).Value
        If IsEmpty(Cells(k, i)) Then
            Cells(k, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        ElseIf Asc(Kibble) <= 32 Then
            Cells(k, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End If
```

In the If statement first I'm highlighting all of the real blank values, and then in the ElseIf portion I'm trying to highlight all the cells stored in that string that's ASCII value is less than 32. I can't get it to run without an error though.

Comment: What is the error message? Which line ?And _all the cells stored in that string_ doesn't make sense. Are you trying to work out the total ascii sum for the cell text?

Comment: Well what the code does is loop through each column first, then row. So during the first loop its in column row and the first row its in row one. Kibble = Cells(k, i).Value is the same thing as Kibble = Cells(1, 1).Value. Once this if statement is finished, the next k will start the loop over again to bring Kibble = Cells(2, 1).Value, and so on.

Comment: What is the error and on which line?

Comment: The error points to the ElseIf statement claiming an invalid argument/ improper procedure.

Comment: What is the value of kibble when this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that kibble is somehow an empty literal string.

Try the following (though you are still applying the same format for both conditions)

```
If Kibble = vbNullString Then
    Cells(k, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
ElseIf Asc(Kibble) <= 32 Then
    Cells(k, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
End If
```

Failing that, please provide the value of Kibble when the error occurs.